# Error in creating Qt project in Visual studio 2015

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5.9

I am trying to create a qt project in Visual Studio 2015.
My qt's version is 5.9.
It was unable to create and a dialog showed with message as below :

```
Operation could not be completed. The project file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\jfqowtaw.vcproj' cannot be migrated. See the migration report for details.
```

"

[image: show error]

I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: you can check in migration report or you can put content of that file here that will be more helpful

Comment: Sr. Where is the migration report? I cannt find this file.